# Spring AOP advice with method rather than @annotation : Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, aspect

I don't understand one thing with the Spring advices. There are two ways which can be used to create an aspect with two advices:

- We can create an empty method with a pointcut annotation. Then, we just have to create methods with an advice which contains the empty method name:

```
    @Component
    @Aspect
    public class TestAppli{

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAppli.class);

        @Pointcut("@annotation(Loggable)")
        public void executeLogging(){
        }

        @Before("executeLogging()")
        public void method1(JoinPoint joinPoint){
            LOGGER.info("method 1 is called");
        }

        @Before("executeLogging()")
        public void method2(JoinPoint joinPoint){
            LOGGER.info("method 2 is called");
        }
    }
```

- We can directly create the two methods with @Before("@annotation(Loggable)") without using an empty method and its name. It seems to realise the same operations (it shows text data into the console too):

```
    @Component
    @Aspect
    public class TestAppli {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAppli.class);

        @Before("@annotation(Loggable)") 
        public void method1(JoinPoint joinPoint){
            LOGGER.info("method 1 iscalled");
        }

        @Before("@annotation(Loggable)") 
        public void method2(JoinPoint joinPoint){
            LOGGER.info("method 2 is called");
        }   
    }
```

Please, can you explain me when the second operation must be used? People say it permits something but I don't understand what the thing is.

Comment: _"People say"_, please provide reference or quotes to what 'people' say. In any case a reason is that you can't always place an annotation (eg third-party code like libraries), so a method pointcut is then the alternative.

Comment: Can explain exactly your need ? ( Votre besoin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concepts of Spring AOP can be read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-defn)

> **Advice**: Action taken by an aspect at a particular join point
>
> **Pointcut**: A predicate that matches join points.

With `@PointCut` annotated method , a pointcut expression to match a join point is declared.

This method name can be then used to associate the pointcut expression with an [Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-advice).

When the pointcut expression is written directly with an advice , it is known as an in-place pointcut expression.

As far as I know , there are no differences when in-place pointcut expressions are used. At the same time the advantage of using `@PointCut` annotated method is that we can [combine](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-combining) several different such methods to have a more readable Advice.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the basics of what a pointcut and advice is.

Second, these annotation-based configuration is just a way to configure the Aspects.  So don't see this as "empty method with a pointcut annotation", but treat it as a syntax of defining pointcut using annotation.

Going back to your question.

Both of them are simply defining some Before-advices.  In your second way, you are putting the pointcut definition directly into the advice definition, while in first way, you are giving a name to a pointcut, and referring it in your advices.

There is no right-or-wrong as long as you know what you are doing.  For example, for very simple and straight-forward pointcut, which is only use in one or two advices, you may put it directly in the advice as in your second way.

However, usually it make sense to give a meaningful name to your pointcut and use it by referring in your advices.  It gives sementic meaning to your pointcut, and make it easier to modify in future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know if i have well understood. Globally, we can use the two ways. The second way (with method) is a cleaner way of writting code. it's better when you have several methods with a specifc advice ?

Comment: Why are you explaining a simple thing in a complicated way? You would use `@Pointcut` in order to **avoid redundancy and enable pointcut re-use.** When updating the pointcut you only have to do it once instead of twice. The literal inline pointcut is IMO better if you only use the pointcut exactly one time. If later you see a need to re-use it, you can still factor it out into a separate pointcut definition.